# Why is this limit infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

$H_n$ is the nth harmonic number. I'm trying to prove that the limit of $a_n = \sqrt[n]n!$ is infinity. I used GM-HM to get $a_n \geq n/H_n = b_n$. Now wolfram alpha says that the limit of $b_n$ is infinity, but on the other hand, $1/b_n = H_n/n$, and the limit of this is infinity, because this is the averages series of the harmonic series. Where am I wrong?

Comment: So the $a_n$ is $(n!)^{1/n}$? (The faculty inside the $n$.th root. No gamma functions involved...) Then why not use Stirling formula?

Comment: @dan_fulea Yes. I havn't learned of striling formula but right now i just want to know where am I wrong

Comment: Are you saying that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{H_n}{n} = \infty$$ or that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n} = \infty $$ when you talk about the average series of $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = \infty $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{H_n}{n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{kn} < \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{kn} \leqslant \frac{1}{n} + \int_1^n \frac{1}{xn}\, dx = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{\ln n}{n} \to 0$

As you need to estimate growth of $H_n$ somehow, I doubt there is much simpler way.

Also, you don't need harmonic numbers or Stirling formula for your original problem. Just note that $n! > k^{n - k}$ for any $k$, so $\sqrt[n]{n!} > k^{1 - \frac{k}{n}}$, so $\sqrt[n]{n!} > \sqrt{k}$ for $n > 2k$. As $k$ was arbitrary it means $\sqrt[n]{n!} \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$H_n\le 1+\log(n+1), \quad\forall n\ge 1$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know why is the inequality true, I am looking for an answer that will be as basic as possible, and I really want to know where was I wrong in my post.

Comment: How do you justify that: The average series of the harmonic series goes to $\infty$?

Comment: I was taught that it is true that when a series converges to a finite limit, then the averages will converge to that limit as well. Isn't that true for infinite limit?

Comment: Yes that is known as Cesaro Theorem. If you are allowed to use it, its ok. My hint avoid Cesàro mean.

Comment: Anyway your use of Cesaro is not clear. You should use it this way: since the sequence $a_n=1/n$ converge at $0$ then the series $(H_n/n)$ too, therefore $n/H_n$ goes to infinity.